# How to generate table with dropped down lists?

Tags: php, excel

For my system when i select a department name from Departments(dropped down list) and a program name from Programs (dropped down list),it should generate a table - reading ax excel file in php. I tried just to read an excel file and it works. How can I connect the selections with the file below in PHP and MySQL?

The code that I found for reading the excel file is below:

Read Excel file

```
<?php
    include 'reader.php';
    $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
?>

Sheet 1:<br/><br/>

<table  border="1">

    <?php
    $excel->read('prog.xls'); // set the excel file name here   
    $x=1;

    while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) { // reading row by row 
      echo "\t<tr>\n";
      $y=1;

      while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {// reading column by column 
        $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
        echo "\t\t<td>$cell</td>\n";  // get each cells values
        $y++;
      }  

      echo "\t</tr>\n";
      $x++;
    }
    ?>   

</table><br/>
```